# How to validate text associated with web element using robot automation framework

Tags: selenium, robotframework

> Website : https://www.diffchecker.com/diff

```
<div class="jsx-1127496569 alert alert-warning " xpath="1" style="">The two files are identical</div>

 [Arguments]      ${locator}    ${expectedString}
 ${Somevariable}=    Get Text     xpath：//div[text()='The two files are identical']
 log to console     ${Somevariable}
 Should Be Equal       ${Somevariable}      ${expectedString}

${response}    Get Text    xpath：//div[text()='The two files are identical']
Should Be Equal As Strings    ${response}    The two texts are identical

${text}=    Get Element Attribute     xpath：//div[text()='The two files are identical']
log to console    ${text}
Should Not Be Empty    $ {text}

${present}=  Run Keyword And Return Status     Element Should Be Visible     xpath：//div[text()='The two files are identical']
     Run Keyword If    ${present}    The two files are identical
```

how to validate element text **The two texts are identical** as each time test is getting pass whether text is present or not on the page

Comment: I would help, if this was a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: The formatting of your code looks broken. You've got some html and robot mixed together, unless your test case is truly named `<div class=...>` Also, can you explain what you've done to debug this? Have you verified that the strings are in fact identical (or not)?

Comment: Yes, I have validated both the cases when string is identical and when string are not identical but both time test is passing and I have tried the same on different sites but and every site I am getting same result. Is there any specific way using that we can handle this kind of text.  this is another example <span class="messageForUser" style="">The two texts are identical!</span> form  https://text-compare.com/